# Traveling from Egypt to Romania with German residence

Tags: germany, residency, romania, egypt, invitation-letters

I had a schengen visa that was expired last April but I extended my residence and now I got a german residence card until next April (I am a student in Germany at the moment)

My question is, if I travel to my home country to see my family and I would like to travel from Egypt directly to Romania, will the German residence suffice?

My reason for traveling to Romania is because my long distance partner lives there with her family so I am just going there to spend the time with them, what could I do regardless of my German residence to gain the right to travel to Romania? What kind of "invitation" would I have to consider?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, if I travel to my home country to see my family and I would like to travel from Egypt directly to Romania, will the German residence [permit] suffice?

Yes, both the two or multiple entry short, and long-stay visas as well as the residence permits issued by a Schengen member state, Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia are sufficient for entry into Romania.

---

**Sources**:

- [VII. Do I need a visa? | Ministry of Foreign Affairs (Romania)](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040)

> **Categories of third-state nationals also exempt from the requirement to be in possession of a Romanian short-stay visa are:**
> ...
> **Holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States.**
> Starting July 11, 2014, in keeping with the provisions of Decision No 565/2014/EU, **Romania acknowledges as being equivalent to its own national visas**, for transit and for stays up to 90 days per period of 180 days the following:
> ...
> [list]